# unexpected line in a plot of function defined by parts - gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot a piece wise defined function give by,

[equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcmTs.png)
Implemented in gnuplot, like this,

```
h(x)=0
g(x)=(4/3)*(1-x**3)
plot h(x)*(x<0) + g(x)*(x>0)*(x<1) + h(x)*(x>1)
```

The problem is that the line that goes from `h(x)` to `g(x)` is not a vertical line, is a inclined one. I really need a vertical one.

How to fix it?
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9lvI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mustn't have (mathematically speaking) a connecting line between the noncontinous parts, because that implies that there are actual function values there.

You should do this instead:

```
plot sample [:0]  h(x) lc 1 title "f(x)", \
            [0:1] g(x) lc 1 notitle, \
            [1:]  h(x) lc 1 notitle
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to increase the sampling rate, for example by

```
set samples 1000
```

Also note that you might have to change the definition of the function g(x) to

```
g(x)=(4./3.)*(1-x**3)
```

because you otherwise evaluate `(4/3)`, which is equal to 1 rather than 1.333...

Comment: I did not know the option to change the samples value. Very useful. Thanks